# Prototype property of function

Tags: javascript

Let we have the following `JS` code:

```
function doThis(){
    myKeys=[];
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    var parent=document.getElementById("parent");
    var child=document.getElementById("child");
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertBefore(span,submit.nextSibling);
    Person.prototype={pr: "pr"};
    var p= new Person("Ivan", "Ivanov");
    myKeys.push(getAllKeyValuePair(Person));
    span.innerHTML=myKeys;
}
function getAllKeyValuePair(obj){
    var str="";
    for(var key in obj){
        try{
            str=str+"{"+key+", "+obj[key]+"}";
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(key);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
function Person(name,surname){
    this.name=name;
    this.surname=surname;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/10/)**
we declare `prototype` property of `Person` constructor function at the line

```
Person.prototype={pr: "pr"};
```

But when I'm trying to print all property of `Person` I'm excepted that we have at least `prototype` properties which indicate to `{pr: "pr"}` object. But if we replace line

```
myKeys.push(getAllKeyValuePair(Person));
```

to the line

```
myKeys.push(getAllKeyValuePair(Person.prototype));
```

we can see the `{pr, "pr"}`.
I don't understand this, please explain me why it's occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAllKeyValuePair(Person)` asks for all the keys on the `Person` constructor function. `Person.prototype` properties are made available to *instances* that have been *built by* the constructor:

```
var p= new Person("Ivan", "Ivanov");
myKeys.push(getAllKeyValuePair(p));
```

The reason you don't see `prototype` when you ask for the properties of `Person` is that `prototype` is a non-enumerable property. You can see this with:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Person, "prototype");
  > Object {
        value: Object,
        writeable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false
    }
```

If you want to enumerate over all of an object's own properties, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person)`. Note that this does not capture properties inherited from the object's prototype chain (thus, we say the object's "own" properties, rather than inherited properties).

Comment: I'm repeat that i'm interested to know: Why we cant see `prototype` property of `Person` explicit? I'm declare prototype property of `Person` at the line `Person.prototype={pr: "pr"};` but function `myKeys.push(getAllKeyValuePair(Person));` doesnt output it to a span.

Comment: @St.Antario: It's non-enumerable, which means that it won't be visited by your `for in` loop. Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person)` instead.